# How to pass image through intent in titanium ?

Tags: android, android-intent, bitmap, appcelerator, titanium-mobile

I am using this code to share the image on different messaging apps and social media sites the code it working fine its sharing the text the installed apps.

```
var intent = Ti.Android.createIntent({
                action : Ti.Android.ACTION_SEND,
                type : "text/plain"
            });
            var text = e.text?e.text:"This text will be shared";
            intent.putExtra(Ti.Android.EXTRA_TEXT,text);
            intent.addCategory(Ti.Android.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
            Ti.Android.currentActivity.startActivity(intent);
```

What I want is to share image type to apps at the place of text I am sharing.
I tried passing values like

```
 Imageview.toImage(),Imageview.toBlob()Ti.Utils.base64encode(Imageview.toImage())
```

I even tried by saving the image in my SD card in the application data directory and tried to pass parameter as

```
 file.read(), file.nativePath
```

etc but no ways is working.Please suggest a solution to this.I checked in java how it works all the procedure is same just they are passing this parameter as bitmap and I am wondering how we can make a imageview to bitmap image.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the traditional method , changing the bitmap to a drawable and then setDrawable of bitmap

Answer (score 0):

May be you can use MultipartEntity

```
MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity(
                HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);          
        reqEntity.addPart("user_profile[image_attributes[attachment]]", bab);
```

Comment: sanu your answer might be correct but as I am developing app in titanium its using javascrip so I am expecting some solution in javascript.